# Netbeans 6.8 update problem

Tags: updates, netbeans

I have been using Netbeans 6.8, but as we know version 6.9 is already available and it is obvious that I want to have the last version. But when I check for updates from Netbeans it doesn't suggest me any updates. Why? Has anybody updated to 6.9 version right from Netbeans? How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded 6.9 a few days ago on my Mac and installed it over 6.8. All settings and projects were kept, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah. Finally it worked on Windows also. It imported all settings from a previous version. Only problem I have is that it could restore setting of my SVN. I think I need to reset configurations of SVN.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the new version.  The built-in updater only applies individual updates applicable to a particular release.  It won't bring you up to the next release.